# Using FoxPro tables with web server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc, persistence, foxpro

I am currently developing a java application which needs to read FoxPro data tables.  I have been using the jdbc-odbc driver to read the table successfully.  What I really need to do though is provide this data through a persistence unit with an eye toward integrating the data with a web server such as glassfish. The FoxPro tables are not linked to a SQL server. I'm not sure this can be done, or how to even approach it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the FoxPro app retired or still in use? If it's retired there will be some work to build a database container that points to remote tables rather than using local (probably free) tables to migrate to SQL Server. If you are retiring the FoxPro code, then you should be able to do a one-off SSIS import with very little pain. (My foxpro experience is thankfully five years in the past now...) definitely recommend moving the tables up to SQL server or another server-based RDBMS.

Comment: The Visual FoxPro app (suite) is still in use and probably will be for  several years.  The work I'm doing is part of the migration away from FoxPro, but we're a small shop and will only be able to do it piece-meal.

Comment: You don't anticipate many simultaneous users of your server-based application, do you?

Comment: If you can budget the migration of the fox app from local tables to server tables, it will make things way nicer for your Java dev.

Comment: Olaf - There will probably be no more than 20 simultaneous users of the application.

Comment: Tetsujin no Oni - I'm not sure what is involved in migrating to server tables.  How much re-engineering of the existing Visual FP apps will need to be done.  It is quite a large suite of apps and we don't have the manpower to make wholesale changes to the data models in the existing apps.  Is upsizing reliable?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Foxpro database as a linked server in SQL Server.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/199131